# error sql oracle "ORA-00936: expression absent"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

What is missing from my SQL?

```
select cl.nom_cl
from client cl
where (cl.id_client IN(select e.id_acheteur
    from enchere e 
    group by e.id_acheteur 
    having(  count(distinct e.idobj) = select count(distinct e2.idobj) from enchere e2 )))
```

> ORA-00936: expression absent: A required part of a clause or expression has been omitted.

Answer (score 0):

I have reconstructed your query to this:

```
  select cl.nom_cl
      from client cl
  where cl.id_client IN(select e.id_acheteur
  from enchere e 
  group by e.id_acheteur 
  having(  count(distinct (e.idobj)) IN (select count(distinct (e2.idobj)) from enchere e2) )  )
```

The `select count(distinct (e2.idobj)) from enchere e2` part of your query could be retrieving more than one records that's why you're getting that error. Another this is `count(distinct e.idobj)` is wrong. It should be like this: `count(distinct (e.idobj))`

Comment: also this is true:select cl.nom_cl
from client cl
where (cl.id_client IN(select e.id_acheteur
            from enchere e 
            group by e.id_acheteur 
            having(  count(distinct e.idobj) = (select count(distinct e2.idobj) from enchere e2 ))  ) )

Answer (score 0):

the true query:

```
  select cl.nom_cl
    from client cl
    where (cl.id_client IN(select e.id_acheteur
                from enchere e 
                group by e.id_acheteur 
                having(  count(distinct e.idobj) = (select count(distinct e2.idobj) from enchere e2 ))  ) )
```

Comment: You can improve your answer by adding a description explaining what was wrong!  This will help others from having to figure out what you changed to fix the problem.